# Docker container is not accessible

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have docker installed on Ubuntu 16.04 VM and I'm working on a personal project using nodejs and Docker image is from the DockerFile. 
the container runs but when I try to access it with the VP'm public IP It's not accessible. 
I tried to curl and I get curl: (52) empty reply from the server. after taking a very long time.
The port is mapped correctly and no firewall issues as well.
here is my docker file

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "npm-shrinkwrap.json*", "./"]
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
        && apk add --no-cache git \
        && apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python \
        && npm install -g nodemon cross-env eslint npm-run-all node-gyp 
           node-pre-gyp && npm install\
        && npm rebuild bcrypt --build-from-source
RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
COPY . .
RUN pwd
EXPOSE 3001
CMD npm start
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             
STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8588419b40c4        xxx:v1             "/bin/sh -c 'npm sta…"   2 days ago          
Up 2 days           0.0.0.0:3000->3001/tcp   youthful_roentgen
```

Comment: How do you start the container?

Comment: are you sure the app is listening on port 3001?

Comment: @omarwaleed yes because I tried running the container as `docker run abc:v1` and it says `server Listening on port 3001`

Comment: @ILoveCode it's not clear to me where did you try to curl the server but have you tried using "docker exec -ti 8588419b40c4 /bin/sh" and then try to curl the localhost by running "curl -X GET localhost:3001" and checking if there is any response?

Comment: I also advice you to check using the shell command that all files where copied correctly and check the logs to see what the app is actually saying

Comment: @omarwaleed yes but it says `/bin/sh: curl: not found` and yes all files are copied

Comment: could you please install curl by running "apk add curl" and test it?

Comment: No response.... still empty reply

Comment: Is the server process listening on 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0?  (May need to check code; some servers print that out as part of their startup messages; if it's 127.0.0.1 you get this symptom.)  Are there firewall rules on either your VM or your host that might be blocking this?

Comment: my port is listening on 0.0.0.0 and I've opened all firewall rules

Answer (score 0):

Let `xxx:v1` be the image name built by the `Dockerfile` you provided.

If you want to access your app via your host (`curl localhost:3001`), then you should run :

```
docker run -p 3001:3000 xxx:v1
```

This command binds port `3000` in your container to your port `3001` on your host (IIRC, `3000` is the default port used by `npm start`).

You should then be able to access `localhost:3001` **from your host** with `curl`.

Note that `EXPOSE` directive in the `Dockerfile` does not automatically expose a port when running `docker run`. It's just an indication telling that your container listens on port you `EXPOSE`d. Here, your `EXPOSE` directive is wrong, you should have written :

```
EXPOSE 3000
```

because only port 3000 is exposed **in the container** (`3000` is the default port used by `npm`). What port you choose to bind on the host (or not) is specified at runtime only.

If you don't want to access your app via `localhost`, but only via the container's IP, there is no need to bind the port (no `-p`). You only need to do `curl <container_ip>:3000` from your host.

Comment: its still an empty reply from server

Comment: With `docker run -p 3001:3000 xxx:v1`, running `curl localhost:3001` from your host gives an error? Is it an empty reply or an error? What is the status code? (run `curl -I` to see only the headers)

Comment: it says `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: Check if your app can be accessed using the container's IP : 1) get container's IP : `IP=$(docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <your_container_name>)` 2) run `curl $IP:3000`

Comment: Yeap.. still `empty reply from server`
but I get this warning that says `
WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.`   when my app is running
Could  this be the issue?

Comment: It could be. Anyway, it looks like port forwarding was not the issue here : your app simply does not reply. I suggest you to edit your question with this error and how you get it, somebody may have an idea.